# How do I get TikTok Login Kit to work with no error?

Tags: ios

I am trying to integrate my app with the TikTok login kit so that users can login with their TikTok accounts from my app.

TikTok has approved me after I set up a business account and a dev account. I have the client key and client secret. However I have tried everything and double checked I am entering the correct information and I keep getting the following error:

> We couldn't log in with TikTok. This maybe due to specific app settings.
> If you're a developer, correct the following and try again client_key

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

I have double checked I am entering the correct client key and secret as it is on the TikTok website but no dice. I have emailed TikTok developer support twice and heard nothing back.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.